# Theoretical question about the predict_prob () function - order of display of the probabilities

Tags: python, predict

I am developing a code for text classification. In total, the problem has 6 different output classes.
I decided to apply two ways to visualize the results of the classification.

First showing the confusion matrix: (It can be seen that I only have the results of 4 classes of output. I believe this is due to unbalanced classes)

Second attempt is to display the odds. For this I used the function:

```
        predict_proba (msg_test)
```

This generates an array with the probabilities for each row in my test suite:

array([[1.14e-04, 2.7e-04, 1.8e-02, 1.17e-01, 7.96e-01, 6.43e-02], [six elements], [six elements], ...,
])

My question is how to find out the order that each value represents from the output class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is ordered by class labels which means that you need to know which class belong to which label. The encoding itself is handled by you (the developer). If you have six class labels (0-5) mapped to six classes of your choice then the order will simply be 0 1 2 3 4 5,

In your example, assuming that you have encoded the classes with numbers 0 through 5, the first column of the `predict_proba` output belongs to class label 0, second belongs to class label 1, and so on

```
[
  [
    1.14e-04, # class label 0, 
    2.7e-04,  # class label 1, 
    1.8e-02,  # class label 2, 
    1.17e-01, # class label 3, 
    7.96e-01, # class label 4, 
    6.43e-02  # class label 5
  ],
  ...
]
```

If you are not sure, you can check the class labels that the classifier is using by accessing its `classes_` attribute

```
clf = someSklearnClassifier...
print(clf.classes_)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: Is the order according to the class name? I applied:

sorted (dataframe_example ['Category']. unique ())

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Order is based on class labels (numbers) not on class names because these libraries work only with numbers. The mapping between class names and class labels can be arbitrary. I can map 0 to red, 1 to green or vice versa. Are you asking about how it handles pandas dataframe?